# Fetching data from a text file in python using re module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I have a text file named `file.txt`
which looks like the below:

```
0,  1,  2.     |classes
A0: 1, 2, 3
A1: 1, 2, 3
A2: 1, 2, 3
A3: 1, 2, 3, 4
| Final Pseudo Deletion Count is 0.  Optimisaiton not possible.
```

From this file I just want to take out the attribute names that is: A0, A1, A2, A3. How can I do it?

I mean for this particular file it is `A0,A1,A2,A3` only but I want the output for in general files. There can be `A0,A1.....An`. Like below :

```
0,  1,  2.     |classes
A0: 1, 2, 3
A1: 1, 2, 3
A2: 1, 2, 3
A3: 1, 2, 3, 4
A4: 1, 2, 3
A5: 1, 2, 3, 4
| Final Pseudo Deletion Count is 0.  Optimisaiton not possible.
```

So in this case the output will contain `A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5`.

I have tried like :

```
f = open('filename1.txt')
attrib1 = f.readline()
    
attrib = []
for i in range(1, len(attrib1)-1):
    v_pos_colon = attrib1[i].find(':')
    attrib.append(attrib[i][0:v_pos_colon])
print(attrib)
```

Comment: No need for a regexp. Just check if the line contains `:`. If it does, split the line and output `line[0]`.

Comment: Yes I have edited my question.

Comment: `f.readline()` just returns one line. Did you mean to use `f.readlines()`?

Comment: Yes it should be f.readlines()

Comment: I thought the name of the file was `file.txt`. Your code uses `filename1.txt`. If the filename wasn't important, why did you specifically mention it in the question?

Comment: Due to some issue with my laptop I was unable to use file.txt, I don't know why, while trying to run the code just now so I copies the content of file.txt to filename1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over the characters in the first line of the file, not looping over the lines of the file.

`find()` returns `-1` when the string isn't found. So when there's no `:` in the line, you're adding the slice `attrib[i][0:-1]`, which slices everything up to the 2nd-to-last character. You should first test whether the character was found.

```
attrib = []
with open('filename1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ':' in line:
            attrib.append(line.split(':')[0])
print(attrib)
```

Comment: It is giving me : print(attrib)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, I left out a `)`